# Exporting IK bones from blender2.8 to unity has problem

Tags: animation, rigging, unity, inverse-kinematics

I'm working blender2.8 with unity3d
but when I export my model from blender to unity
My Bone plays animation so weird see this

[image]

[image]

First picture in on unity. second one is on blender2.8
Two legs have IKBones and i guess these IKBone is having trouble.
I put all keyframes of all bones at every each frame but it still don't work.
Does somebody know why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out.
I've re-rigging(?) my model at IKLegBone parts.

1. Delete IK constraint.
2. Change both side of calf bone's rotation a little bit.
3. Add IK constraint.

Finish!
If it doesn't work, repeat 2 differently.